# Windows Vista Update shows no updates in list

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update

My Windows Update keeps telling me that I have 5 (put your random number here) important updates to install. However, when I click on them, the list that pops up is empty. I can still install the updates, but I cannot see and of course also not decide which updates are going to be installed.

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows Vista. Sometimes goes away after a reboot, but not fun at all.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I tried http://superuser.com/questions/123623/windows-7-update-shows-no-updates-in-list and some other things, but still the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, both on my laptop, and my work computer (home office). [This answer](http://superuser.com/questions/69227/windows-vista-update-shows-no-updates-in-list/198760#198760) from Noah does not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that Microsoft Support are very good at these type of problems which go to the core of their operating system.  I would email them, or even phone them if they supply a freephone number for your area.

I have to admit that such calls go one of two ways, you are either stunned how easy and efficient they are, or it's a nightmare of holding redirecting, in which case I would just hang up.

Comment: Thank you. Not the answer I expected, but helpful, too ;) I'll report back.

Comment: I would vote you up, if I could ;)

Comment: What in the world? They don't even accept my product ID! Probably because it's OEM and you can forget the support at the computer manufacturer...

Answer (score 0):

This can occur from a corruption in the Cryptographic service database log

The following steps will delete the log, which will be automatically rebuilt as needed

```
Click the Start 
type cmd in the Search all programs 
right click cmd.exe, click Run as administrator, Agree to the UAC prompt

At the command prompt, type the following commands:
      net stop cryptsvc
      ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2\edb.log *.tst
      net start cryptsvc
      exit
```

After every is working again, go ahead and delete the edb.tst file

Comment: did not solve the problem for me.